# How to unfocus the user dialog while it is being displayed in matlab?

Tags: list, matlab, button

If, e.g, a script contains button or a list it seems that the user is unable to edit other objects (e.g like figures) while the button or list box is actively being displayed on the screen. Therefore I would like to ask if I can "unfocus" the button so that I can freely edit the desired object (e.g zoom in/out, add manuallly a legend etc.)?

E.g:

```
while indx == 1

    list = {[...

            'Choose_option',...

           'The data file will be exported (with a total of_____'... 
            num2str(height(EXPORT))'_____datapoints)'],...
           };
        
[indx] = listdlg('SelectionMode','single','ListString',list,'ListSize', [600 300]);
    
    switch indx

        case 1
               % placeholder
        case 2 
            source_1      ='D:\MyFile\Programm_alpha\Test.xls';
            destination_1 ='D:\TargetEXPO\Programm_beta'
            copyfile(source_1 , destination_1);                   
            xlswrite(source_1,{'Begin_reading'},'Sheet_1','A1'); 
                
    end
end
```

Comment: If additional information is required pls notify in the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`listdlg` creates a [modal dialog box](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/listdlg.html#d122e748789), which means it disables interaction with everything else in MATLAB until the dialog box is closed. The same is true for `inputdlg` and `questdlg`.

If you want to have a non-modal window where the user can select things, you will have to build this yourself. You will need [`uicontrol`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) for this. A good place to start is by looking at the code for `listdlg` (it used to be a plain M-file back in the day, not sure if it still is though).

Comment: thanks I will work with the uicontrols then if listdlg is now usefull anymore